# decide entity type programmatically in .net entity framework 6

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a method updating certain record with id, and there is some entities have same structure with that table so I wonder how can I do something like below;

```
    public void deleteCarwithId(int id, int type)
            {
                string[] brands = { "BMW", "VOLKSWAGEN", "RENAULT", "FIAT" };
                T entity = Convert.ToEntity(brands[type]);//ofc there is no such a method yet
                var result =UnitOfWork.Repository<entity>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
                result.IsDeleted = true;
                Update(result);
            }
```

instead this(it works but ugly);

```
public void deleteCarwithId(int id, int type)
    {
        string[] brands = { "BMW", "VOLKSWAGEN", "RENAULT", "FIAT" };
        if (brands[type] == "BMW")
        {
            var result = UnitOfWork.Repository<BMW>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
            result.IsDeleted = true;
            Update(result);
        }
        if (brands[type] == "VOLKSWAGEN")
        {
            var result = UnitOfWork.Repository<VOLKSWAGEN>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
            result.IsDeleted = true;
            Update(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why have you created separate entities for the different car types? Why isn't the car make just an attribute on the entity?

Comment: because there is too many specific columns for each car... I wish I could do what you advice but cant in this scenario

Comment: Naming conventions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to achieve this is using reflection and `MakeGenericMethod` function:

1st: create an interface for types you want to delete in future:

```
public interface IDeletable
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

2nd separate a logic function based on created interface structure

```
public void Delete<T>(UnitOfWork unitOfWork, int id) where T: IDeletable
{
    var repository = (Repository<T>)typeof(UnitOfWork).GetMethod("Repository")
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T)).Invoke(new UnitOfWork(), new object[0]);
    var item = repository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    item.IsDeleted = true;
    Update(item);
}
```

3rd call the function with specified type

```
public void deleteCarwithId(int id, int type)
{
    var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Delete"); // Binding parameters could requires
    switch(type)
    {
        case 0: method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(BMW))
                .Invoke(this, new object[]{unitOfWork, id});
                return;
        ...
    }
}
```

As alternative to reflection, can be used a dictionary of repositories:
Assuming that 1st step from above has been done and that your repository is **`IQueryable`**, than the method can looks like:

```
public void deleteCarwithId(int id, int type)
{
    var source = new Dictionary<int, IQueryable<IDeletable>>
    {
        {0, unitOfWork.Repository<BMW>() }
        // all other types
    };
    var repository = source[i];
    var item = repository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    item.IsDeleted = true;
    Update(item);
}
```

Of course, to reduce amount of unnecessary initializations, the `Dictionary` can be created as a field in the hosting object or even as a static field. In  case of static field repositories will be **never** collected by GC.